# Structure map - Conditionally select a concrete type for an interface based on the type of the instance to which the dependency is injected

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have two wcf rest services as follows

```
using StructureMap;

namespace x.services
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
                /* How do I configure Structure map to Use 
                   x.services.service1.Validator for constructing 
                   x.services.service1.Service1 Instances and
                   x.services.service2.Validator for constructing 
                   x.services.service2.Service2 Instances ** */
            }
    }
    public interface IValidator
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
namespace x.services.service1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Service1(IValidator validator)
        {
            /*...*/
        }
    }
    public class Validator : IValidator
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
namespace x.services.service2
{
    public class Service2 : IService2
    {
        public Service2(IValidator validator)
        {
            /*....*/
        }
    }
    public class Validator : IValidator
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

The question goes here too

**How do I configure Structure map to Use x.services.service1.Validator for constructing x.services.service1.Service1 Instances  and x.services.service2.Validator for constructing x.services.service2.Service2 Instances**

Comment: What you're missing here is a generic type. Change the `IValidator` to `IValidator<T>` and let `x.services.service1.Validator` implement `IValidator<Service1>` and let `x.services.service2.Validator` implement `IValidator<Service2>`. This effectively removed the ambiguity and possibly even makes it easier to implement a validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use explicit mapping:

```
// As precise IService1 mapping as possible
x.For<IService1>() 
   .Use<x.services.service1.Service1>()
    .Ctor<IValidator>("validator")
     .Is<x.services.service1.Validator>();

// IService2 
x.For<IService2>() 
   .Use<x.services.service2.Service2>()
    .Ctor<IValidator>("validator")
     .Is<x.services.service2.Validator>();
```

EDIT: to make some type singleton

```
x.For<x.services.service2.Validator>()
  .Singleton()
  .Use<x.services.service2.Validator>();
```

Comment: Also can u please tell me How to set x.services.service2.Validator Instance as Singleton in the same usage

Comment: Will this wrong then?  

x.For<IAuthenticator>().Singleton().Use<Authenticator>();

Comment: If you mean: will it work? Of course! ;) this is the essence of StructureMap ... ala IoC container. You've got the point! Exactly ;)

Comment: Good luck with StructureMap. Amazing Tool ;)